# my message isn't displaying on unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have 3 scripts. One controls everything for the player, another controls everything for the tutorial, and the other just has info on the objects for the tutorial. I am trying to display a tutorial message when the player goes into a trigger. One of my variables doesn't work how I think it should be though. Here is the code that is relevant to my question (the first and third methods aren't completely shown because they are long).

The Player script where it accesses the tutorial script:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
//detects tutorial
    if (other.transform.tag == "Tutorial")
    {
        tutorial = tutorial.GetComponent<Tutorial>();
        tutorial.showLevelTutorial ();
    }
```

Tutorial class :

```
public void showLevelTutorial()
{
    getLevelInfo (); //gets info from trigger on what to display
    showMessage = true; //sets the message to show

    if (messageNum == 2) //gets the timer to start counting
    {
        count = true;
    }
}
/*
 * called from the showLevelTutorial method. It gets info from the trigger.
 */
void getLevelInfo()
{
    levelPrompt = trigger.getPrompt ();
    messageNum = trigger.getNum ();
}
void OnGUI()
{
 //levelTutorial
    if (levelTutorial)
    {
        if (showMessage) //shows tutorial
        {
            print ("about to show message");
            if (messageNum == 2)
            {
                if (timer <= 200)
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/2 - Screen.width/2 *.5f, Screen.height/2 - Screen.height/2 * .5f, 600, 70), levelPrompt, skin.GetStyle ("Tutorial"));
                if (timer > 200 && timer <= 400)
                    GUI.Label (new Rect(Screen.width/2 - Screen.width/2 *.75f, Screen.height/2 + Screen.height/2 * .1f, 300, 70), "This will take you back to your home so that you can buy markers.", skin.GetStyle ("Tutorial"));
                if (timer > 400 && timer <= 600)
                    GUI.Label (new Rect(Screen.width/2 + Screen.width/2 *.3f, Screen.height/2 + Screen.height/2 * .1f, 280, 70), "This will take you to the next level.", skin.GetStyle ("Tutorial"));
                if (timer > 600)
                    GUI.Label (new Rect(Screen.width/2 - Screen.width/2 *.5f, Screen.height/2 - Screen.height/2 * .5f, 600, 70), "For now, let's go back home.", skin.GetStyle ("Tutorial"));
            }
            else
            {
                setTime ();
                Rect TutorialRect = new Rect(Screen.width/2 - (Screen.width*.5f/2), Screen.height/2 - (Screen.height*.5f/2), Screen.width *.5f, Screen.height *.5f);
                GUI.Box (TutorialRect, "");

                if (GUI.Button (new Rect(TutorialRect.x + TutorialRect.width - 170, TutorialRect.y + TutorialRect.height - 60, 150, 40), "Go"))
                {
                    showMessage = false;
                    setTime ();
                }
                GUI.Label(new Rect(TutorialRect.x + 40, TutorialRect.y + 30, TutorialRect.x, 70), levelPrompt, skin.GetStyle ("Tutorial"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested all of the variables in this code and I absolutely cannot figure out why the showMessage variable is true in the showLevelTutorial method, and then suddenly false again in the onGUI method.  There isn't any statements that even set showMessage to false that could be accessed here.

I would really appreciate some help here! :)

Comment: You don't appear to have included the code where you declare the variable `showMessage`.

Comment: I declared the variable `showMessage` in the tutorial class as a global variable. It is private and is set to be true. I also use this variable in the tutorial class for the world tutorial, and I needed it to be set as true for that. For some reason though, as I was debugging, `showMessage` goes from being true to being false without me putting anywhere in the code for it to turn back to false. I'm not sure where my logic error is. Do you think it's something to do with the fact that I'm calling the methods from a different class? @Qubei

Comment: Sorry there's too much code, and too much missing. You'll get a better response if you cut it down to its the bare minimum so you can post it all.